# how to display tables in flexdashboard using a loop

Tags: r, dataframe, loops, flexdashboard

I am trying to display the iris df in 3 tabs, according to species type, in a flexdashboard.  Unfortunately the dfs are not displaying in the tabs. Any advice would be appreciated.

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: fill
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
library(tidyverse)
```
```{r}
tab_vector <- c("setosa", "versicolor", "virginica")
``` 

```{r results="asis"}
# I specified as header to this section {r results="asis"}

cat("## Column {.tabset}\n")
cat("#### Tables\n")

for(tab in tab_vector){
  cat(paste("### ", tab, "\n"))
 
  iris %>% 
    filter(Species == tab) 
}
```
````

Comment: iris %>% 
    filter(Species == tab) |> kable() |> print()

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because of low quality

Answer (score 1):

Here's an option using `knitr::knit_expand`

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: fill
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
library(dplyr)
library(knitr)
```

```{r}
tab_vector <- c("setosa", "versicolor", "virginica")
``` 

# Level 1 Header

## Column {.tabset}

```{r include=FALSE}

res = lapply(tab_vector,\(tab) {
  knit_expand(text = c("### {{tab}} \n",
                       "```{r}",
                       "iris %>% filter(Species == '{{tab}}')",
                       "```"))
})

```
`r paste0(knit(text = unlist(res)), collapse = '\n')`
````

Comment: Many thanks Jamie. I will incorporate this code using kable